# Building Credential object needed for Firebase Reauthentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

When trying to build the credential object to reauthenticate a user with Firebase and ReactJS, I am getting *cannot read property 'credential' of undefined* where `undefined` is referring to `this.app.auth.EmailAuthProvider` which should be `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider`.

I have read that it is a static method and cannot be called on an instance, but I am not sure what exactly that means or how to correct my implementation to get the credential needed. I am calling the method in a class based component, but I am still unaware of how all of this ties in to calling a static method.

The method that I am calling is 'this.app.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential()'

```
    reAuthUser = (data) => {
    // console.log('email: ', data.userEmail, 'password: ', data.password);
    const userCredential = this.app.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        data.email,
        data.password
    )
    // this.currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(data.userEmail, data.password)
    //     .then(function() {
    //         alert('user has been reauthenticated')
    //     }).catch(function(error) {
    //         console.log('reauth error: ', error)
    //     })
};
```

This is in ReactJS, in a class component. `this.app` is a reference to Firebase and it is called in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.app = Firebase;
    this.currentUser = this.app.auth().currentUser;
};
```

I know similar questions have been asked and answers have been approved, but they don't make much sense to me at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `this.app.auth` is an instance of the `firebase.auth.Auth` class, `EmailAuthProvider` won't be present on that object, as it is not part of the prototype for the `firebase.auth.Auth` class.

`EmailAuthProvider` is instead part of the `firebase.auth` **namespace** which means it can only be accessed using `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider` (note how `auth` is not called as a function).

If using imports, you could also use

```js
import { auth as FirebaseAuth } from 'firebase';

FirebaseAuth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(...)
```